# Изменение alpha у bitmap

Tags: android, java

Пытаюсь поменять альфаканал, на выходе одно и тоже при разных значениях альфы.

```
image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.my_image);
shinyImage = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(),border);
shinyImage.setAlpha(0);  // Альфа!
image = shinyImage.getBitmap();
```

Кто-нибудь понимает почему так?

Comment: я не понимаю, что у вас написано то. Зачем первая строка, если у вас в итоге image = shinyImage.getBitmap()? Что такое border? Что вы хотите получить в итоге?

Comment: а вы уверены, что у битмепа есть альфа-канал?

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap bgr = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.logo);       
Paint transparentpainthack = new Paint();
transparentpainthack.setAlpha(100);
canvas.drawBitmap(bgr, 0, 0, transparentpainthack);
```